# How to create a dialog in the Fragment from the Activity using the Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a dialog in the Fragment directly from the Activity using the Navigation component.

The only solution I have found is this below.

Anyone have a better solution?

In Activity:

```
private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController
}

private fun openDialogAbout() {

    val finestraDialogo = Dialog(navHostFragment.requireContext())
    finestraDialogo.window
    finestraDialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    finestraDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_about)
    finestraDialogo.setCancelable(true)
    finestraDialogo.show()

    val window: Window? = finestraDialogo.window
    window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from the Fragment with some modifications.

```
private fun openDialogAbout() {

    val finestraDialogo = Dialog(requireActivity())
    finestraDialogo.window
    finestraDialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    finestraDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_about)
    finestraDialogo.setCancelable(true)
    finestraDialogo.show()

    val window: Window? = finestraDialogo.window
    window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

}
```

Comment: Your answer is not helpful. 
I want to create a dialog in the Fragment directly from the Activity.

Comment: In that case, you can use shared ViewModel and Live data. You can subscribe to a live data object in an activity and post value to this live data during any event from Fragment. As you subscribe to live data from the activity hence you can show your dialog.

Comment: Rabiun, It could be a solution, although I don't really like using ViewModels for other purposes than for data.
However your idea should work. Thank you